# input from textbox as output with native GWT?

Tags: variables, gwt, text, label

In my project i have different images with a textbox included , which can be dragged and dropped on a boundaryPanel. The user can enter a text in the dropped image and click a button, which opens a popup.

Depending on the input, i want to generate a output in this popup:

`SET INSERT a.{variabletext},b.{variabletext},...`

I have no idea, how to solve that with native GWT. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I absolutely don't understand your problem.

Comment: it's a forum, so i think it's justifiable when i ask things i don't understand...